# Merge on Date Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Df1

```
Date
2016-10-02
2016-08-22
2016-09-16
```

Df2

```
Low_Date        Week
10/2/2016       Week 1
07/22/2016      Week 2
09/16/2016      Week 3
08/22/2016      Week 4
11/16/2016      Week 13
```

All columns are dtype: object

I'd like to end up with the following in Df1:

```
Date        Week
2016-10-02  Week 1
2016-08-22  Week 4
2016-09-16  Week 3
```

I've tried:

```
Df1 = pd.merge(Df1,Df2,left_on='Date',right_on='Low_Date',right_index=False)
```

However this returns an empty dataframe.  Is it something to do with how the dates are structured?  I don't particular care how they are structured, just want the week number.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are your dates strings? if so they won't match you need to convert to datetime and then merge `df2['Low_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Low_Date']` and likewise for the other df

Comment: Oops!  This fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: Should one of you post that as an answer, maybe including how to to transform the dates (`pd.to_datetime`), so we can mark the thread as accepted?